# Question about Vectors and Gradients

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

[image]

Attached above is the question that I'm struggling with, specifically part b. I was able to get the gradient as 12s**i** + 10t**j**, however I don't know to find the point where the gradient vanishes. Can someone please explain to me what are the next steps, without telling me the answer, so that I am able to solve part b

Comment: Check your work. The gradient you’ve computed isn’t even close to correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the gradient is $u(s,t)i+v(s,t)j$, then the gradient vanishes when $u(s,t)=0$ and $v(s,t)=0$.

Solve for $s$ and $t$.

Edit:

\begin{align}f(s,t)&=(1-s-4)^2+(1+s-1-t)^2+(2-2s-2t)^2\\
&=(3+s)^2 +(s-t)^2+(2-2s-2t)^2 \end{align}

Can you use chain rule rule to differetiate with respect to $s$?

Can you use chain rule to differentiate with respect to $t$?

Comment: Wait wouldn't that mean that the point would be (0,0). How does that make sense?

Comment: see the edit. you might like to check your gradient again.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my gradient. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you obtain $12si+10tj$?

Comment: I realized that my gradient is wrong but i don't know how to calculate it. Can you help me in calculating it

Comment: See the edit, try to use chain rule?